# How to change my App's language using text view onClick?

Tags: android

I want my App to change it's language to spanish when a user clicks on textview (Spanish), and so on with different langs. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change language programatically in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its simple  :

```
private void setLocale (String localeCode , Bundle b ){
    Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    UserDetail.this.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    onCreate(null);
}
```

Call the above function from your onclick method over textView, you can set which ever language you want :

```
...
setLocale("es",savedInstanceState); // for Spanish
setLocale("en-us",savedInstanceState); // for english
...
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: It says expression expected at the second line Locale = ..

Comment: I have changed code, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks! But it says again, "parameter b is never used" . And onClick text view="setLocale" doesn't work too. What to do ??

Comment: Well that's okay, you can remove that parameter from function, I used it in my code for some other purpose...